# My CSS document is present in the Head but not tying any of the styles to the element

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

I have a few css files that are working like a charm in the head of my default.aspx template. We are trying to add a Custom CSS input field from the dashboard of our website builder. It is .net and the code for the head that gets rendered server side is:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litCustomCSS"></asp:Literal>
```

The codebehind for that bit is:

```
if (s.ToLower().Equals("websiteid"))
{
    // check if the customCSS file exists in the proper directory
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteImagePath"] + "/" + pageInfo.ReturnValues[s] + "/CustomCSS.css")))
    {
        litCustomCSS.Text = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' id='customCSS' src='" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteImagePath"] + "/" + pageInfo.ReturnValues[s] + "/CustomCSS.css' />";
    }
}
```

The odd part is it works... as in the file shows up in the head of the rendered page (client-side), but doesn't appear to work. As in if I add a custom CSS class for body or whatever it doesn't append the styles to that element. It's not visible in inspect element, but I can view the css file by itself by clicking on the link in the head.

For instance on this site (http://tworockguns.com/home.html) the css line is

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="customCSS" src="/site_data/2830/CustomCSS.css">`

Which links to the css file http://www.tworockguns.com/site_data/2830/CustomCSS.css

I added the CSS through the backend as:

```
.footer-bottom {
background: #111111;
color: #555;
}
```

Which you will see did get succesfully transfered to the css doc.

I tried changing the charset... changing the order of the css files... and still nothing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the src to href and it will work. It does for me at least on your site.

Comment: This worked! Thanks my friend! I had the biggest DOH moment when I saw that. src is for scripts href is for links... duhhhhh